# R Shiny Interactive Decision Tree Predictions

Tags: r, tree, shiny, decision-tree

I am currently trying to figure out how I can make a Shiny application that takes user inputs and uses them to create predictions based off a decision tree. My problem is quite simple and I think it may come down to understanding.

First, I create a simple tree (using tree library):

```
tr<-prune.tree(tree(Y~., dataset,split="gini"),best=4)
```

Note that I have 20 variables.

If I plot this tree, I see that only 5 of these variables are actually used in creating the tree. Naturally, in my Shiny application I would prefer the user to have to input the smallest amount of information possible. But, the prediction only works if the user inputs absolutely everything (all 20 variables, even though only 5 are used).

Here are my multiple attempts at getting around this:

First I tried to create a data frame with only the relevant information:

```
predict(tr,newdata=data.frame(PREVIOUS=1.6,CONS_PRICE_IDX=96,EMP_VAR_RATE=-3.1,CAMPAIGN=1.4,NR_EMPLOYED=5000),"class")
```

This returns me the error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Object 'AGE' not found" (where age is another variable).

(I get the same error if I use `list()` instead of `data.frame()`).

Then I tried to create the following data frame that accounts for all variables, but still treats the variables not included in the tree as irrelevant:

```
predict(tr,newdata=data.frame(AGE=NULL,MONTH=NULL,DAY_OF_WEEK=NULL,PDAYS=NULL,POUTCOME=NULL,JOB=NULL,EURIBOR3M=NULL,CONS_CONF_IDX=NULL,MARITAL=NULL,EDUCATION=NULL,DEFAULTCREDIT=NULL,HOUSING=NULL,LOAN=NULL,CONTACT=NULL,PREVIOUS=1.6,CONS_PRICE_IDX=96,EMP_VAR_RATE=-3.1,CAMPAIGN=1.4,NR_EMPLOYED=5000),"class")
```

This returns me the error

> Error in data.frame(AGE = NULL, MONTH = NULL, DAY_OF_WEEK = NULL, PDAYS = NULL,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

If I use `list()` here then I get the error

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.pass, xlev = object$xlevels) :
> invalid type (NULL) for variable 'AGE'

Basically, I don't understand why R seemingly needs data for values that aren't actually included in the decision tree. The prediction will work if I fill in every single value, but that would be highly tedious for a user. Is there any way to get around this?

EDIT:

My tree created with this formula:

```
tr<-prune.tree(tree(Y~., dataset,split="gini"),best=4)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Checking which variables are actually used:

```
summary(tr)

Variables actually used in tree construction:
"PREVIOUS"       "CAMPAIGN"       "EMP_VAR_RATE"   "CONS_PRICE_IDX" "NR_EMPLOYED"
```

Then, creating the following tree:

```
tr2<-prune.tree(tree(Y~PREVIOUS+CAMPAIGN+EMP_VAR_RATE+NR_EMPLOYED+CONS_PRICE_IDX, dataset,split="gini"),best=4)
```

Yields:

[image]

As you can see.. this tree is completely different and basically useless.

Comment: Did you have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302628/used-variables-in-tree?

One idea would be to find out variables used are prunning, ala feature selection and then reconstruct a tree based on only those variables.

Comment: @discipulus I did indeed try this, but if I reconstruct the tree with only the relevant variables, for some unknown reason, the tree completely changes. I will add an edit to show what I mean.