# Extracting variable names from decision tree

Tags: r

So i have built a decision tree in R with the `tree` package and running the summary() function on the tree gives me:

```
Classification tree:
tree(formula = High temperature ~ ., data = summer.train)
Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] "Humidity"      "Cloudy"   "Airy" "Dry"   
"Windy"
Number of terminal nodes:  12
Residual mean deviance:  0.3874 = 377.7 / 975 
Misclassification error rate: 0.08909 = 89 / 999
```

I would like to get the variables that is used by the tree construction, "airy", "dry", etc based on the summary function above. Is there any way i could do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is link to :

[Used Variables in Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302628/used-variables-in-tree)

Indeed, the solution is working for me, I used the famous spam dataset to test it :

```
library(kernlab)
library(tree)

data(spam)

spam_tree_def <- tree(type~.,data=spam)
summary(spam_tree_def)
```

The summary result :

```
Classification tree:
tree(formula = type ~ ., data = spam)
Variables actually used in tree construction:
 [1] "charDollar"      "remove"          "charExclamation" "hp"              "capitalLong"     "our"            
 [7] "capitalAve"      "free"            "george"          "edu"            
Number of terminal nodes:  13 
Residual mean deviance:  0.4879 = 2238 / 4588 
Misclassification error rate: 0.08259 = 380 / 4601
```

The way to extract what you want :

```
as.character(summary(spam_tree_def)$used)

[1] "charDollar"      "remove"          "charExclamation" "hp"              "capitalLong"     "our"            
 [7] "capitalAve"      "free"            "george"          "edu"
```

Comment: just the regular tree package